# Unable to connect kafka server if i set broker.id other than 0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect kafka server with one node. If i set `broker id  = 0` then it runs fine, but if I change this from 0 to any number (like 1,2,3,etc) then not able to connect server

my configuration of zookeeper.properties are

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5 
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=60
```

and server.properties file

```
broker.id=1
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

Comment: but do you have brokers with those ids? or, why do you want to change the id?

Comment: Change `listeners` config to `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092`. If there is only one node, the configuration has no error. But I recommend, before change `broker.id` delete your `zookeeper` data and restart.